# How to say "Graduation" in Latin?

Tags: word-request

How do you say the word "graduation" in Latin, referring to a college graduation?  I searched online, but couldn't find anyone who had asked this.

Answer (score 5):

David Morgan, in his *Lexicon*, offers ***promotio [academica]***. [Lewis & Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dpromotio) says that this is a post-classical word and offers "advancement, preferment, promotion" as translations.

A "graduation ceremony" would be ***promotionis sollemnia***.

Comment: This is a good choice, especially if one wants to refer to the graduation ceremony. At my university, the "conferment of degrees ceremony" (as it's called in English) is called "promootio" in Finnish and *promotio* in Latin. However, this celebration is not obligatory; one will graduate whether or not one attends a "promotion" in any way (even *in absentia*).

Answer (score 4):

Two ideas from the University of Oxford, which still conducts some of its ceremonies (including degree days) in Latin:

- **Encaenia** is a Greek word for a festival of renewal, which is the name of Oxford's ceremony celebrating benefactors and conferring honorary degrees. The [university website](http://www.ox.ac.uk/news-and-events/The-University-Year/Encaenia) describes the term as equivalent to the American term 'commencement' for the chief ceremony of the academic year.
- A [regular degree ceremony](https://www.ox.ac.uk/sites/files/oxford/field/field_document/Degree%20ceremony_201617_web.pdf) uses the phrase **Gradus conferre** for the granting of degrees in the opening formula (although when students are specifically admitted to degrees, the phrasing is **admittere ad gradum**). This suggests some sort of expression like **ceremonia gradum conferentis** could be apposite.

Comment: I'd recommend *conferendi* over *conferentis*.

Answer (score 3):

Two suggestions:

1. If Etymonline is to be trusted, the English word "graduation" comes from a medieval Latin adjective *graduatus* ("graduated").
   This Latin word is a regular derivation but seems to be absent in classical literature.
   If *barbatus* is "bearded" and *alatus* is "winged", *graduatus* is "degreed".
   The word *gradus* can mean "status", "degree", or "position".
   Going by analogy with *graduatus*, it is natural to translate "graduation" as ***graduatio, -nis***.
   The benefit is that it looks obviously related to the English word and is readily understood (in context) by most Latinists even if they have never seen the word before in Latin.
2. The Finnish–Latin–Finnish dictionary by Reijo Pitkäranta translates "to graduate" as *specimina absolvere* and lists no other options.
   More directly, this Latin expression means "to finish one's exams".
   Based on this, you could call "graduation" as *specimina absoluta* (lit. "completion of exams").
   Frankly, I dislike this option.

Answer (score 3):

In Medieval *studia generalia*, the term that seems to have been used is *[gradum](https://la.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradus_academicus) concedere* or *conferre*. Alternately, instead of *gradum*, the name of the degree: *baccalaureus* for those who finished the *trivium*, *magister* for those who finished the *quadrivium*, and *doctor* for those who finished the higher *facultates* of Law, Medicine or Theology.

Comment: Hmm... Aren't *baccalaureus* and *magister* people who hold the degrees, not the degrees themselves?

Comment: I think that there's some [metonymy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy) in play for that kind of usage, but yes, formally they're the titles for the holders of the degrees.

Answer (score 3):

In DMLBS (*Dictionary of Medieval Latin from British Sources*), a dictionary of Medieval Latin, we can find the deponent verb **graduārī** for "to graduate", and the substantive usage of its perfect participle **graduātus** for "a graduate", e.g.:

> unum de clericis nostris, virum [...] in utroque jure **~atum** (*see the [DMLBS entry](https://logeion.uchicago.edu/graduari) for details*)
> ad [...] prepositum et ceteros de collegio **~atos** debet pertinere

The noun **graduātiō** for "graduation" is also attested:

> dignior quo ad **~onem** scolasticam debet preferri

Personally, I am not a fan of pure Classical Latin, so I would prefer these simple words for brevity in most circumstances.